# Function pointer in Template

Tags: c++, templates

In a old code I am seeing function pointer is used in template:

```
typedef int (*get_max)();

template<get_max FUNC>
get_max func()
{
        return FUNC;
}
```

As I am new to template, I am lost and trying to google for more same theories how this is possible. Any link of book where this is described? Thanks in advance

Comment: it is possible, but stupid thing to do

Comment: The term to google for is "non-type template parameter".

Comment: @BЈовић Why exactly is it stupid?

Comment: @jrok Cause you need to specify function as the template type when calling `func()`. Here is example : https://ideone.com/e3GN2m

Comment: I'm sure the code in OP is just an example.

Comment: @ Sebastian Redl Thanks for this term...

Comment: If the template calls the function it's more useful - for each instantiation the exact function is a known constant so it can be compiled as a direct call (or even inlined), no indirection needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global functions have known addresses of known sizes, so they can be used in compile-time expression, e.g. as template parameters. On standard x86 platforms that address has 32 bits, on x64 - 64 bits (that's why for storing it you shouldn't use `int`, which has 32 bits on both platforms, but rather `intptr_t`).

So what the code is doing is returning a pointer to a function the `func` function has been specialised for. Internally, it simply returns an address of passed function. What may have confused you is that function names decay to function pointers (i.e. you don't have to use `&` to get function's address)

You can also create a template with a parameter being an address of a global non-static variable, if you are in these kind of things. It helps to understand what's going on in your original example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<int* p>
int* useless_proxy()
{
    return p;
}

int foo = 666;

int main()
{
    std::cout << *useless_proxy<&foo>() << std::endl; // prints 666
};
```